# Getting more than 1000 documents using folder() in Appian

Tags: appian

I am writing an Appian web API, to retrieve documents from our Appian system which will be used to integrate with our other systems.

To this end, I am using the `folder()` method to get information about the contents of a folder in Appian.

```
folder(
    theCaseFolder,
    "documentChildren"
)
```

The problem I am having is that while this code works most of the time - we have some cases where there are more than 1000 documents stored against the case.  I note that the [Appian documentation](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/18.4/fnc_scripting_folder.html) states that:

> The documentChildren and folderChildren properties return up to the first 1000 documents or folders, respectively, that are direct children of the selected folder.

My problem is that we have a few cases where there are more than 3000 documents attached to the case.  Is there a way to get a list of of those child documents, or am I plain out of luck?

Comment: Store all those IDs in a process variable and query the folder again but without those IDs?

Answer (score 1):

In long term I would suggest storing some information about document in separate table in db. In this way you can query db as you wish by Appian or by SQL.

In short term you can get first 1000 as it is in documentation and then move them to subfolder/different folder or delete. This can be repeated multiple times to get all files from folder.

[Move Document Appian Function](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/18.4/Move_Document_Smart_Service.html)

Comment: Although it looks like a workaround, that's probably the way to go.